# How do UTAM Webdriver Jasmine work together? What is the layer architecture?

Tags: test-automation, jasmine, utam, webdriver

The article [UTAM - Write UI Test](https://utam.dev/guide/js-guide#write-ui-tests) contains these bits

> **Use assertions** ... to ensure that your test returns expected results. Use any assertion library of choice, such as Node.js assertions.
>
> **Run tests** The process to run tests depends on your test automation framework
>
> **Use Jasmine to structure tests** Jasmine is a behavior-driven development framework for testing JavaScript code. This repo uses a WebdriverIO Jasmine plugin that's an adapter for the Jasmine testing framework.

[Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/index.html)

I would like to ensure that my understanding of all dependencies / components and how they play together is correct.

Based on the images ([img1](https://webdriver.io/assets/images/webdriver-97575d94ce4d11618b595acd1496a887.png), [img2](https://webdriver.io/assets/images/devtools-becb0a3d3f3e2b6e049bb99883760286.png)) at [WebDriverIO](https://webdriver.io/docs/automationProtocols) i assume the following

```
SF page    UTAM provides                     WebDriver        Browser Edge
DOM    --> Page Objects --> test code    --> UTAM methods --> run Webapp
                            uses PO to       are used to      execute Tests 
                            access DOM       connect to 
                            jasmine to       WebDriver to
                            structure tests  send commands to
                            webdriver to     the browser
                            send commands  
                            to the browser
                            X? to run assertions
```

Is the above correct?

From the [provided sample test](https://github.com/salesforce/utam-js-recipes/blob/main/force-app/test/record-create.spec.js) are these code snippets

```js
describe('Record creation tests', () => {
    const testEnvironment = new TestEnvironment(TEST_ENVIRONMENT_PREFIX);
    const baseUrl = testEnvironment.redirectUrl;

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await login(testEnvironment, 'home');
    });
```

I assume that [`describe()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.1/global.html#describe) and [`beforeAll()`](https://jasmine.github.io/api/5.1/global.html#beforeAll) are from the Jasmine library.

I assuem the following lines are using the UTAM library

```js
 const recordFormModal = await openRecordModal(baseUrl, RecordType.Opportunity);
 const recordForm = await recordFormModal.getRecordForm();
 await recordForm.clickFooterButton('Save');
```

But I do not understand when and how webdriver comes into play. The [Introduction to UTAM](https://utam.dev/guide/introduction) states

> For JavaScript tests, UTAM provides an adapter between UTAM page objects and the browser API that WebdriverIO provides.

Based on the statement above and the name `clickFooterButton()` i assume that this is the connection between the test and the event to send to the browser. UTAM `methods` take care to send commands to WebDriverIO.

#### Question

- Is my understanding / are my assumptions above how the components play together correct?
- Which of the components above is the automation framework?
- What library takes care of assertions?

Comment: Can someone with more reputation create tags for `UTAM` and for `Webdriver`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure my descriptions aren't right, but I've created the tags for you. Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is my understanding / are my assumptions above how the components play together correct?

I don't think I'd describe the "layers" that way. They're a bit more complicated. If I had to graph my understanding, it'd look more like this.

```
  Web Brower/DOM
       ⬆️⬇️
     WebDriver        Salesforce
     ⬇️     ⬆️           ⬇️
  Jasmine   UTAM  ⬅️ Page Objects
     ⬇️     ⬆️
     JavaScript
```

WebDriver starts up a browser, and interfaces between that and the testing framework, e.g. Jasmine. Jasmine then calls the appropriate JavaScript unit tests, which will involve working with WebDriver. UTAM provides an adapter relationship where it translates Page Objects into WebDriver commands. Salesforce provides the UTAM PO data with each release/update.

You can still access WebDriver directly through JavaScript without UTAM. However, this forces your scripts to be more reliant on the Salesforce DOM not changing. You want to use UTAM to avoid having DOM changes break your unit tests. The entire point of UTAM is to make DOM access more reliable, even as the internal structure of the app changes over time.

> Which of the components above is the automation framework?
>
> What library takes care of assertions?

Jasmine is the automation framework. WebDriver's role is to start up a browser, then start up the selected framework. The framework itself provides methods describing tests, setup, and teardowns. Similarly, assertion logic is provided by the Jasmine framework. Your JavaScript can call various Jasmine methods to assert that values are equal, are present, etc. UTAM's goals are to translate various things you want to do with DOM elements into WebDriver commands to update or retrieve DOM elements, using Page Objects as the DOM relationships to query for.

Comment: I assume above javascript stands for the tests code that has to be written?!  
Do you have experience with UTAM or Playwright?  We are yet unexperienced with UI testing and tried playwright first. Since we are separated from the salesforce developers and we have not yet talked to them about creating PO with the utam-generator for all custom classes we are on the fence if the switch to UTAM will be benefical over playright. Any advise or experience you can share?

Comment: @surfmuggle Yes, in this answer, JS refers to the tests you write. I have zero practical experience with UTAM, Playwright, Jasmine, or Selenium, but I understand how they work in theory, having read about them. As such, I don't have a recommendation based on experience, but in theory, I'd say that since salesforce.com developed UTAM, it's likely going to provide a better experience in the long run.